# PHP RabbitMQ Consumer: Prefetch 1

Tags: php, rabbitmq

To avoid common concurrency problems I have single threaded php consumers that consume several messages from one rabbitMQ queue.

Basically its the same php script executed X times and waiting for new messages.

**My question is:**
Is correct to assume that **as my consumers are single threaded** I set a prefetch configuration of 1 message?

[PHP Prefetch Count RabbitMQ](http://php.net/manual/pl/amqpchannel.setprefetchcount.php)

Because obviously it wont **process** more than 1 message at a time...
Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefetch is simply a number of messages that the broker will put on the consumer side and remove them only after those messages were acknowledged. Now, if we assume that the client(consumer) is processing one message at the time, then this number *prefetch_count* is not really important. But, if the clients are *consuming* messages in one thread, and then spawning new threads - each to process one message, then it's obviously a different story. So one could say that multi-threaded acknowledging is more of a story.

Since you wrote *single threaded consumers* I'm pretty sure you mean the entire client is single threaded, not just the "consuming" portion, so the **my direct answer** is you can set it to 1, but you don't have to, it's depending more on the way you are ACKing the messages. I just wanted to elaborate on multi-threaded processing part.

Comment: Now I understand more. I should have elaborate more my question, because currently the client can consume all the messages he wants, but because of the single threaded nature of the consumer it can only *process* one at a time, therefore only one ack at a time.

Comment: Exactly. That's why when I'm discussing with colleagues, we always say that "consuming" is just transferring messages to client, and processing and ACKing soemthing else :)